# Python Selenium - Click Youtube Comment Like

Tags: python, selenium

im trying to click the first Like Button in the comment section of a youtube video.

```
    driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=da-WNRaEIlM&lc=z22gt5sq2wu3dzvsgacdp431i5qvtq4t3pikmyg0aoxw03c010c')
    time.sleep(10)
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "ytd-toggle-button-renderer", " " ))]')
    elem.click()
```

But he doesnt find this element, can someone help?

Comment: The xpath in the code is for comment or like?

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS locator:

```
'div[data-cid="z22gt5sq2wu3dzvsgacdp431i5qvtq4t3pikmyg0aoxw03c010c"] button[aria-label="Like"]'
```

z22gt... it's the comment ID, and in your case is in the url